# is connected complex Lie group with a trivial center linear?

Tags: algebraic-groups, lie-groups

There is a theorem of Rosenlicht ("Some basic theorems on algebraic groups", 1956, Theorem 13) asserting that a quotient of a connected algebraic group by its center is linear. So a connected algebraic group with trivial center is linear.

Is it true of connected complex Lie groups? I.e. is a connected complex Lie group with a trivial center a subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$? Is it algebraic?

Comment: Rosenlicht's term "algebraic groups" includes *non-affine* examples such as abelian varieties.    But a "complex Lie group" is more narrowly defined.   So your last formulation of the question is unclear.   Early in Chevalley's treatment of affine algebraic groups he shows that such a group is linear, whereas some familiar real Lie groups are not.   The detailed structure/classification shows that complex semisimple Lie groups are indeed linear, but for solvable Lie groups you'd have to look further into Hochschild's work including his old book *Structure of Lie Groups*, etc.

Comment: I have just noticed that I have written "algebraic" where I should have written "complex Lie". I am sorry, the question should read: are connected complex Lie groups with trivial center linear algebraic?

Comment: @Jim Humphreys: I must be missing something. In what respect is "complex Lie group" more narrowly defined? Doesn't "complex Lie group" meean a group which is a complex manifold with the group operation a holomorphic map? This definition seems to cover groups that are not subgroups of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$, like complex tori. I wondered if the Rosenlicht's result generalised from algebraic varieties to complex manifolds. I perhaps mixed two notions together. First, I wonder if a connected complex Lie group with a trivial center is a subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ [continued]

Comment: ...and second, if it is an _algebraic_ subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ (i.e. an algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$ with group law a regular map)

Comment: @ Dmitry: The answer to your first question ("is a connected complex Lie group with a trivial center, a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$?") is clearly yes: look at the adjoint representation of a Lie group $G$, it is classical that its kernel is $Z(G)$. So if $Z(G)$ is trivial, $G$ is linear. 

Comment: @Alain: this only gives an injective homomrphism into $GL_n$. Is it clearly an embedding, i.e. an isomorphism onto a closed subgroup?

Comment: &Laurent: I haven't checked carefully right now but I think that if $G$ is a connected complex Lie group $f:G\to GL_n(\mathbf{C})$ is an injective continuous homomorphism, then the diagonal homomorphism into $GL_n(\mathbf{C})\times G/\overline{[G,G]}$ is proper (i.e. has a closed image).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Alain Valette says, a centreless connected complex Lie group $G$ has an injective homomorphism into $GL_n({\mathbb C})$. However, it need not be algebraic. To see this, consider the semi-direct product $G={\mathbb C}^2 \rtimes {\mathbb C}$. Here $z\in {\mathbb C}$ acts on the standard basis $e_1,e_2$ by the characters $e^{2\pi i z}$ and $e^{2\pi i z/\sqrt{2}}$ respectively. If $G$ can be given the structure of an algebraic group, then these two characters on ${\mathbb C}$ would become algebraically dependent, which cannot be.

Incidentally, this $G$ is not closed in its adjoint "embedding", since the closure contains $S^1\times S^1$ in the diagonal part. That is $G\subset {\mathbb C}^2\rtimes D_2$ where $D_2$ is the group of diagonals in $GL({\mathbb C}^2)$.

Comment: Dear Aakumadula, could provide a bit more detail? I do not understand what you mean by having a structure of an algegbraic group. Does it mean being a closed subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb C)$? How does that imply that the two characters should be algebraically independent?

Comment: Dear Dima, 

the question is "is a connected complex Lie group algebraic"? I understand it to mean that given a complex Lie group $G$, can you put the structure of a complex algebraic group $G'|$ such that as complex LIE groups, $G$ and $G'$ are isomorphic? 

Now suppose that the $G$ in the example is a complex ALGEBRAIC  group (in the foregoing sense). $e_1,e_2$ may be thought of as  elements of the Lie algebra, which is necessarily an algebraic representation of $G$, and are eigenvectors for $G$. But, $${\mathbb C}^2$ acts trivially, and hence $G$ acts via a one dimensional group on the span

Comment: of $e_1,e_2$. Hence the two algebraic characters $\chi _1, \chi _2$ of the image of $G$ (which is one dimensional) must be algebraically dependent i.e. there exist integers $m,m'$ such that $\chi ^m=\chi ' ^{m'}$. 

Comment: Perhaps I should add that the image o an algebraic group under an algebraic homomorphism is also an algebraic group